# This problem is regarding union of two arrays and I'm getting an error showm below

Tags: arrays

```
//{ Driver Code Starts
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


// } Driver Code Ends
class Solution{
    public:
    //arr1,arr2 : the arrays
    // n, m: size of arrays
    //Function to return a list containing the union of the two arrays. 
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    vector<int> findUnion(int arr1[], int arr2[], int n, int m)
    {
        set<int>st;
        int arr1=n.size();
        int arr2=m.size();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            st.insert(arr1[i]);
        }
        for(inti=0;i<m;i++){
            st.insert(arr2[i]);
        }
        vector<int>temp;
        for(auto it:st){
            temp.push_back(it);
        
        }
        return temp;
        
        //Your code here
        //return vector with correct order of elements
    }
};

//{ Driver Code Starts.

int main() {
    
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    
    while(T--){
        
        
        
        int N, M;
        cin >>N >> M;
        
        int arr1[N];
        int arr2[M];
        
        for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
            cin >> arr1[i];
        }
        
        for(int i = 0;i<M;i++){
            cin >> arr2[i];
        }
        Solution ob;
        vector<int> ans = ob.findUnion(arr1,arr2, N, M);
        for(int i: ans)cout<<i<<' ';
        cout << endl;
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
// } Driver Code Ends
```

Why do I get an error like below?

./Solution.cpp: In member function 'std::vector Solution::findUnion(int*, int*, int, int)':
./Solution.cpp:16:13: error: declaration of 'int arr1' shadows a parameter
int arr1=n.size();
^
./Solution.cpp:16:20: error: request for member 'size' in 'n', which is of non-class type 'int'
int arr1=n.size();
^
./Solution.cpp:17:13: error: declaration of 'int arr2' shadows a parameter
int arr2=m.size();